# Removing a Marker in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to remove a *marker* that was initialized like this:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: 'Marker 1',
    icon: redPin
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    showMarkerDialog(marker.position, "marker");
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function() {
    // Add a alert: Are you sure you want to remove this marker?

    map.removeOverlay(marker);
});
```

Everything works perfectly except that when I double click it to remove what I get on the Error Console is this:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'removeOverlay'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, "everything" works "perfectly" except your _entire_ removal mechanism.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is no *removeOverlay* function on the *map* object.  Sounds like you've got only one marker, why use an array?  Just change this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function() {
    map.removeOverlay(marker);
});
```

to this:

```
marker.addListener("dblclick", function() {
    marker.setMap(null);
});
```

Comment: What if I have multiple markers and want to remove a specific one? Could I reference "marker[index]"?

Comment: Yes, have an array of all your markers, you can then reference them like that.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer you can read more on this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove